# cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_eh

Tags: c, gcc

Im trying to compile a program on my windows machine with cygwin and im facing this error

```
cannot find -lgcc_eh
```

Seems like a missing dependancy or a flag issue, heres the Makefile

```
CC      = gcc
STRIP = strip -s --remove-section=.note --remove-section=.comment
TARGET  = resource_tool

HEADERS = resource_tool.h common.h
SOURCES = resource_tool.c common.c
OBJS    = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

CFLAGS  = -fshort-wchar -m32 -ffunction-sections -Os
LDFLAGS = -Wl,--gc-sections -static 

SOURCES += tests.c
HEADERS += tests.h

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS) Makefile
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
    $(STRIP) $@
```

Ive done some research but cant find anything that has helped

Comment: Try installing devel files for GCC. "*Such is the nature of Cygwin*"

Comment: @JL2210 Im currently using the devel package, ive also tried the mingw GCC with no success

Comment: Try installing the 32-bit versions of the packages.